# can jQuery $.ajax be used without exchanging/returning data in ASP.Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I only want to update a startDate in an XML file so I do not really need anything back. Is some sort of returned data required for using jQuery $.ajax?

If so can I just return a boolean? If so how would I do that?

JS

```
function updXmlStartDate() {
    //
    alert("post");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx/UpdateImageStartDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (result) {
            alert("yay!");
        },
        error: function (result) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
    });
}
```

VB

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function UpdateImageStartDate(ByVal newStartDate As String) As String
    'update xml
    Dim var1 = 1
End Function
```

Right now I have a Breakpoint set on the .NET Function but it is not reaching it.

Comment: your ajax needs to include a `newStartDate` parameter...also just change the return type from String to bool in the `UpdateImageStartDate` declaration

Answer (score 3):

As was commented on the question by @Logan Murphey, the data field in your ajax object needs to be set to `data: "{'newStartDate':'" + yourstartdate + "'}"` or `data:JSON.stringify({newStartDate:yourstartdate})`.

You are also sending a "POST" in your ajax call.  For your service to get it, the service class must have the `<ScriptService()>` tag and your method must have the `<ScriptMethod()>` tag in addition to the tags automatically added to your Service class and methods.

Example:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
<ScriptService()>
Public Class Service
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Function MyMethod() As Boolean
        '... do some work ...
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is an excellent tool for checking why Service calls aren't being hit.  I strongly recommend using it or something similar when first learning to make asynchronous calls to a web service.  The information it can tell you is invaluable in debugging things like:

- Incorrect path to Web Service
- Improper or missing Service tags on Service class or Service methods
- Many other things too... it's worth exploring

Comment: Your correction works, however, the newStartDate field does not require quotes around it.  They are redundant.

data: "{newStartDate: '" + yourstartdate + "'}"

AND

data: "{'newStartDate':'" + yourstartdate + "'}"

are equivalent.

JSON.stringify(...) is a good approach, but keep in mind that old IE browsers do not have the JSON.stringify function available and need to be shimmed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

You need to send your input parameter as `Json` object:-

```
function updXmlStartDate() {
    alert("post");
    input = { newStartDate: "hello" };
    var strRequest = JSON.stringify(input);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx/UpdateImageStartDate",
        data: strRequest,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (result) {
            alert("yay!");
        },
        error: function (result) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
    });
}
```

Also, you can simply return a boolean from your `WebMethod` like this:-

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function UpdateImageStartDate(ByVal newStartDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim var1 = 1
    Return True
End Function
```

And retrieve it at client side as:-

`result.d` which will give you the returned boolean, either 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: the dataType should be json...you should change your data

Comment: @LoganMurphy - Whats `input` in my post an XML?

Comment: but now you have to change `dataType : "json"`

Comment: @LoganMurphy - That was obviously a typo!